# Where are located Application Insights Telemetry logs in Azure Portal

Tags: asp.net, azure, logging, azure-application-insights

I have this class:

```
public class TelemetryHelper : ITelemetryHelper
{
    private TelemetryClient TelemetryClient { get; set; }

    public TelemetryHelper()
    {
        TelemetryConfiguration configuration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
        configuration.InstrumentationKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"];
        TelemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(configuration);
    }

    #region Input

    public Task InfoAsync(DebugMessageType tag = DebugMessageType.Other, string message = null, Exception ex = null, [CallerMemberName] string callerFunction = "", [CallerLineNumber] int lineNumber = 0)
        => OutputInApplicationInsightsAsync(SeverityLevel.Information, tag, message, ex, callerFunction);

    public Task ErrorAsync(DebugMessageType tag = DebugMessageType.Other, string message = null, Exception ex = null, [CallerMemberName] string callerFunction = "", [CallerLineNumber] int lineNumber = 0)
        => OutputInApplicationInsightsAsync(SeverityLevel.Error, tag, message, ex, callerFunction);

    public Task WarnAsync(DebugMessageType tag = DebugMessageType.Other, string message = null, Exception ex = null, [CallerMemberName] string callerFunction = "", [CallerLineNumber] int lineNumber = 0)
        => OutputInApplicationInsightsAsync(SeverityLevel.Warning, tag, message, ex, callerFunction);

    #endregion Input

    private Task OutputInApplicationInsightsAsync(SeverityLevel level, DebugMessageType tag = DebugMessageType.Other, string message = null, Exception ex = null, string callerFunction = "")
    {
        var properties = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Tag", tag.ToString() } };

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(callerFunction))
            properties.Add("CallerFunction", callerFunction);

        if (ex != null)
            properties.Add("Exception", ex.ToString());

        TelemetryClient.TrackTrace(message, level, properties);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

And I can use it like this:

```
await TelemetryHelper.ErrorAsync(DebugMessageType.Service, ex.Message, ex, nameof(this.RunRemoveTasksAsync));
```

However, can someone tell me where are these logs in Azure Portal.. I've been searching for hours I can't find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the application insights is linked correctly and telemetry data are sent successfully, you can find it via these locations in application insights.

First nav to azure portal -> the application insights you linked in your code.

**Location 1:**

In the application insights -> Search -> you can select a proper "time range" and "event type" -> then click the "Refresh" button. You can see the logs:

[image]

**Location 2:** In the application insights -> Logs. You can write the proper [Kusto query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/log-query-overview) to see your logs. I see you're using `TelemetryClient.TrackTrace` method, so your logs should be in the **traces** table. You can follow the screenshot below for more details:

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, I didn't understand at first, that's why I missed it I think. Yes, anytime someone's providing the right answer, I accept it and upvote it don't worry :)